# How can we get image of user using Google Calendar api?

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I'm following [this example](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android) but I coudn't know how I can get the image of selected account name(user). here I created mCredential value like in the example as below:

```
mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
            getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
            .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff())
            .setSelectedAccountName(settings.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null));
```

I was not able to get image via mCredential value. Thank you for helps in advance.

Comment: people.get returns image  https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get

Comment: but according to that page we get the image of person calling plus api. Person mePerson = plus.people().get("me").execute();  but I don't use plus api.

Comment: What I am saying is that you need to use an API to get the data.  Authentication isn't going to return the picture of the person authenticating.

Comment: I was thinking that I could get personal informations with GoogleAccountCredential but now I added plus api and I can get them as you showed. Thank you very much.

Comment: You might try and hack it a little.   If the auth is returning a user id, I cant remember what it returns.   you could maybe request the user info from plus.people using a public API key.   then the user wouldn't need to approve the plus api scope.  Just an idea worth looking into.

Comment: It is worth to try :) I will consider this too. thank you again :)